# How to implement subscript and superscript in legend (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I am wondering how to implement text in a legend with both a superscript and a subscript, and with an horizontal bar, something like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smQ3E.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That quesion is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to use some $\LaTeX$-style text in MATLAB, you have to specifiy the corresponding `Interpreter` option to use LaTeX. For a legend with your provided example this works with

```
legend("$\bar{H}^{front}_{debris}$",'Interpreter','latex')
```